# ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

I have worked around but not able to fix the solution,
I became a collaborator for a private repository, and now I am cloning that repository so I am getting this error.
I cross-verified ssh-key in my github account, Its all there in place.
I can clone other repositories in which also I am as a collaborator.
Dont know why, when cloning this repository its giving me the error.

Comment: Can you currently clone public repos from GitHub? If not, then it's probably a temporary connectivity issue with GitHub.

Comment: Yes, I am able to clone public repos from github

Comment: Are you sure you're actually a collaborator for the private repo?

Comment: Yes, I can see that repository in My github home page in "Your Repositories" section on right panel of the page.

Comment: You might have already check but it's better to double check: have you checked Github's https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found page. It might help.

Comment: Yes, I went throuh this page - https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found, but still not able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add manual git configuration for specific host with specific ssh-key,

touch ~/.ssh/config

vi ~/.ssh/config

Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

That's It!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today.

Starting the ssh-agent

$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

and confirming my identity

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

fixed the issue, even though I could ssh -T git@github.com successfully before.